# Converting simulink blocks to code for a GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, output, packet, simulink

I would like to create a GUI in MATLAB that has two sliders that can be used to adjust the value a and b. I know I can get the GUI to open simulink and have simulink do this and then packet the information using UDP as shown in the following image:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pkxomQi.png]

However, I would prefer to be able to convert these simulink blocks to code in the GUI slider. More specifically, I am interested in coding the packet output block so the GUI button can send the information. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you know the "path" to the block, you can set / get its parameters using [`set_param`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/set_param.html) and [`get_param`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/get_param.html). In your case, the first Constant block has the path `'rtpacketio/Constant'` - that is, the system name followed by a `/`, followed by the name of the block.

To find out which parameters are available for the block, you can do,

```
>> get_param('rtpacketio/Constant', 'DialogParameters')

ans = 

         Value: [1x1 struct]    <<< This is the one you need to change
VectorParams1D: [1x1 struct]
  SamplingMode: [1x1 struct]
        OutMin: [1x1 struct]
        OutMax: [1x1 struct]
OutDataTypeStr: [1x1 struct]
     LockScale: [1x1 struct]
    SampleTime: [1x1 struct]
   FramePeriod: [1x1 struct]
```

Note that the values of these parameters are not `struct`s - the struct array that is returned from the `DialogParameters` parameter represents information about the parameters; when you set or get a block's parameter it must be a string (because it's going into an `edit` control). In the code where you want to set this parameter, then, you can do the following:

```
set_param('rtpacketio/Constant', 'Value', num2str(myConstantValue));
```

You may wish to replace `num2str` with a more accurate equivalent, if you require high precision.

Comment: So with this method, then Simulink has to be running right? Because what I need to do is be able to communicate with a target PC that controls a robotic arm. It would be nice to have a GUI that transfers data through UDP without opening Simulink. By using the slider, the information is transferred directly to the target PC. Is this possible?

Comment: I believe the DSP toolbox comes with TCP and UDP blocks for Simulink, so you could run a model locally with a TCP send and a model on the controller with a TCP receive and send your command data that way. Another option is [this FileExchange submission](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13721-distributed-parallel-simulations-with-simulinkr-and-other-tools), which is pretty good, although it's a little bit ... quirky, and doesn't come with source. You could probably just open up a TCP connection directly to the TCP Receive block, but I've never done it so don't know much.

Comment: Thanks wakjah. So for your first post, that method requires Simulink to be open right? And the GUI can edit the parameters by using set and get right? Just want to make sure.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to use UDP Objects (http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/creating-a-udp-object.html) to do the same thing in the DSP toolbox and send information to a Packet Input block as shown here http://imgur.com/v4lCn2d. In this case, the code sends the constant value and performs the same job as the Packet Output block.

Comment: It should be; I'm not familiar with these "Packet" blocks - they must be new in 2013 - but I've certainly done a similar thing with the old UDP Receive block (in fact, there's no reason that the data *has* to even come from a program running in MATLAB). Give it a go!

Comment: YEEE I almost got it, I can currently send out packets in type int8. Unfortunately it doesn't work with double or anything else although I'm not exactly sure. Still a great start and thanks for your help! UDP Object definitely worked. So EXCITING lololol

Comment: If want to know all the details about what my problem is, here is the question I posed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754867/using-fwrite-in-matlab-to-graph-constant-double-values-in-simulink-scope-blocks.